# Clear radio-buttons after completing forms

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button

I'm having a series of userforms, making a questionnaire. Each userform consists of a couple optionbuttons/checkboxes. The program works fine.
However, when I start the program again (without quitting Excel) the radiobuttons and checkboxes are filled in the same way like the previous user did.

I tried with each userform initialization to call to a module:

```
Option base 0

Sub clearBtns()
Dim optBtn(10) As Variant
optBtn(0) = "optA"
optBtn(1) = "optB"
optBtn(2) = "optC"
optBtn(3) = "optD"
optBtn(4) = "optE"
optBtn(5) = "chkA"
optBtn(6) = "chkB"
optBtn(7) = "chkC"
optBtn(8) = "chkD"
optBtn(9) = "chkE"
optBtn(10) = "chkF"

Dim cnt As Integer
For cnt = 0 To 10
    If Not optBtn(cnt) Is Nothing Then
    optBtn(cnt).Value = False
    End If
Next cnt

End Sub
```

unfortunately this doesn't work (error 424, object required). It has probably something to do with this part:

```
If Not optBtn(cnt) Is Nothing Then
```

There has to be an easier way to do this.
For extra information: after each form is completed, I use:

```
Me.Hide
form_x.Show
```

The last form is different, with:

```
Unload Me
```

Maybe there's a problem?

For further explanation:

```
Option Base 0

Public Sub clearBtns()

Dim optBtn(10) As Variant
optBtn(0) = "optA"
optBtn(1) = "optB"
optBtn(2) = "optC"
optBtn(3) = "optD"
optBtn(4) = "optE"
optBtn(5) = "chkA"
optBtn(6) = "chkB"
optBtn(7) = "chkC"
optBtn(8) = "chkD"
optBtn(9) = "chkE"
optBtn(10) = "chkF"

Dim formArray(27) As Variant
formArray(0) = "page1_1"
formArray(1) = "page1_2"
formArray(2) = "page1_3"
formArray(3) = "page2_1"
formArray(4) = "page2_2"
formArray(5) = "page2_3"
formArray(6) = "page3_1"
formArray(7) = "page3_2"
formArray(8) = "page3_3"
formArray(9) = "page4_1"
formArray(10) = "page4_2"
formArray(11) = "page4_3"
formArray(12) = "page5_1"
formArray(13) = "page6_1"
formArray(14) = "page6_2"
formArray(15) = "page6_3"
formArray(16) = "page7_1"
formArray(17) = "page7_2"
formArray(18) = "page7_3"
formArray(19) = "page8_1"
formArray(20) = "page8_2"
formArray(21) = "page8_3"
formArray(22) = "page9_1"
formArray(23) = "page9_2"
formArray(24) = "page9_3"
formArray(25) = "page10_1"
formArray(26) = "page10_2"
formArray(27) = "page10_3"

Dim cnt As Integer
Dim fCnt As Integer

For fCnt = 0 To 27
    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        formArray(fCnt).Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
Next fCnt

End Sub
```

Above code doesn't work.

```
Public Sub clearBtns()

Dim optBtn(10) As Variant
optBtn(0) = "optA"
optBtn(1) = "optB"
optBtn(2) = "optC"
optBtn(3) = "optD"
optBtn(4) = "optE"
optBtn(5) = "chkA"
optBtn(6) = "chkB"
optBtn(7) = "chkC"
optBtn(8) = "chkD"
optBtn(9) = "chkE"
optBtn(10) = "chkF"

Dim cnt As Integer

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page1_1.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page1_2.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page1_3.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page2_1.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page2_2.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page2_3.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page3_1.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page3_2.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page3_3.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page4_1.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page4_2.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page4_3.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page5_1.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page6_1.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page6_2.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page6_3.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page7_1.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page7_2.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page7_3.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0
    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page8_1.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0
    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page8_2.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page8_3.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page9_1.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page9_2.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0
    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page9_3.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page10_1.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page10_2.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt
cnt = 0

    For cnt = 0 To 10
    On Error Resume Next
        page10_3.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
    Next cnt

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Above code works, but it takes a lot more code and is very inefficient.

Comment: why are you just Hiding these forms? can you not unload them aswell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There has to be an easier way to do this. For extra information: after
>   each form is completed, I use:
>
> ```
> Me.Hide
> form_x.Show
> ```
>
> The last form is different, with:
>
> ```
> Unload Me
> ```

Instead of using `Hide` on all the forms use `Unload`. The `Userform_Initialize` method will **only** be called when the forms are actually initialized - this does NOT happen when you show a formerly hidden form.

So, when you do something with these forms like

```
form1.show   'initialize called
'stuff that changes the form attributes
form1.hide
form1.show    'initialize NOT called
```

You need to either use `Unload` or move your code into the `UserForm_Activate` method of each UserForm (which may cause you other issues depending on how these are actually being used).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your array: "optA", "optB" etc are actual names of controls. The error occurs because `optBtn(cnt)` does not refer to an object, but only a string value from your array.

Based on that to achieve what you are seeming to want, replace this code:

```
For cnt = 0 To 10
    If Not optBtn(cnt) Is Nothing Then
    optBtn(cnt).Value = False
    End If
Next cnt
```

with this code:

```
On Error Resume Next
For cnt = 0 To 10
    Me.Controls(optBtn(cnt)).Value = False
Next cnt
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: What exactly does the "Me.Controls"-part do? I think I have to replace "Me" with "UserForm" or something like that, since this code is in a module? (I get an error message that I can't use the keyword 'me')

Comment: It works if I put the form name (i.e. form1) instead of "me". But when I put all form names in an array and put array(x) instead of "me" it doesn't work. Why is that? Without an array I have to use a lot more code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I assumed that all of your code was in the userform itself. If you want to use an array for your forms, you'll need to use a format like `formArray(index).Controls(controlsArray(Index)).value = False`.

Comment: I tried that, but for some reason it doesn't work with an array? Example: formArray(0) =  "page1_1" formArray(0).Controls(controlsArray(Index)).value = False doesn't work

Comment: Post the code you are using to create the form array, and we can help you get it right.

Answer (score 0):

This will reset (deselect) all option buttons on 'Userform2Clear'

```
Dim opt as Control
For Each opt In Userform2Clear.Controls
    If TypeName(opt) = "OptionButton" Then opt = False
Next
```